# Do long-running main-thread scripts block scroll painting?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, google-chrome-devtools

For example in the below timeline, I'm scrolling up and down between 3s mark and 7s mark. The scrolling does not appear to be smooth. The closeup is the first and largest block of scripting (200ms). My understanding is that the browser cannot both do main-thread JS and paint at the same time. Is that correct? If yes, then if that block of script is removed, then the green painting section that follows can be performed sooner, thereby resulting in smoother scrolling?

[image]

Closeup:

[image]

Comment: Yes, JS blocks the UI. Did you try removing that block of code to see if it improves?

Comment: The question you're asking is entirely implementation dependent and probably even depends upon the host CPU configuration (how many cores).  It is not specified in any HTML or ECMAScript specification exactly when painting happens.  You will need to test on relevant platforms to see what works best.  JS can block repaint, but it can also trigger a synchronous repaint in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and yes. Move long-running JS to a worker.